# Fried ASUS laptop with universal charger?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

Several days ago, the charger for my ASUS K50IJ laptop (19V, 3.42A) died. So, I bought an Omega universal charger with 11 different plug-ins, but I managed to first use the wrong plug-in (I later saw in the instructions it was for IBM, 16V 3.5/3.36/4.5A).

It didn't charge, so I managed to find the right plug-in, but that didn't charge either. Then I tried a friend's original ASUS charger (that one worked previously), and that won't charge either. Plus, I could smell burning for a sec coming out of the laptop.

So, did I fry the charging unit in the laptop? Can that be repaired? Thanks!

Comment: If you could smell something burning then you did indeed damage the laptop.  The adapter you used provided more Amps then the hardware was designed to handle.

Comment: Too many amps should not be a problem. The laptop shouldn't draw more amps than it requires. Too many volts can be a problem. I am not sure why this fried the laptop, I would have thought that too few volts would just have charged the laptop slowly or done nothing. Maybe polarity was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a burning smell that doesn't sound good. Taking it to a laptop repair store they'll be able to tell you for sure what the problem is. It definitely sounds like you've toasted part of the laptop but I don't think anyone, without physical access to the laptop, will be able to tell you for sure what is wrong.